# Can I use the iOS .strings files for anything other than localization?

Tags: cocoa-touch, localization

I would like to put all the images that I use in my application into the same file and access them by key.

Is it possible to use the .strings file for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want to put the image **names**, yes it's possible.

In your code, just use things like `[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(key, @"")];`

Where `key` is the key that points to the name of your image. Then in the .strings files, point to the right image file based on the locale.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can! I use it to list website URLs used in my app.  This makes it extremely easy to change in the app, if the website URL ever changes.  There is no problem with doing this.